# MySQL fails to stop and authenticate

Tags: mysql

I'm tried to setup new database for second Wordpress blog
i did

```
root@TheLove:/# mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 108


mysql> CREATE DATABASE wp_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wp_name.* TO name@name.com IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> quit
Bye
```

and after that i get this errors when i want to stop/restart/authenticate

```
mysql -uroot
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

/etc/init.d/mysql stop
Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld failed!

mysqld --skip-grant-tables
130126  0:23:57 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130126  0:23:57  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
130126  0:23:57  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
130126  0:23:57  InnoDB: Retrying to lock the first data file
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
```

so i did

```
pkill mysql
/etc/init.d/mysql start

Starting MySQL database server: mysqld.
Checking for corrupt, not cleanly closed and upgrade needing tables..
root@TheLove:/# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

also tried the password located at
cat /etc/mysql/debian.cnf

```
Starting MySQL database server: mysqld.
Checking for corrupt, not cleanly closed and upgrade needing tables..
root@TheLove:/# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
cat /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```

i couldn't figure this after reading a lot of tutorials also find out some people had this issue before and they couldn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

Try to shutdown your MySQL one more time (or simply kill it). Now you could start mysqld by hand with skipped grant tables. Then you could reset your password

```
shell> mysqld --skip-grant-tables & 
shell> mysql 
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('newpassw0rd'); 
mysql> flush privileges;
```

Looks to me like you recently restored or migrated your database from an mysqldump with different credentials in the `mysql.user` Table. This often has no affect until you use `flush privileges;`

Comment: @noqque i tried to kill by 'pkill mysql' and after i type mysqld --skip-grant-tables results long flooded error like in second code above

Comment: sorry for confuse after i killed mysqld thats worked i was able to write --skip-grant-tables mysqld --skip-grant-tables
130126 10:56:30 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130126 10:56:30  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
130126 10:56:30  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130126 10:56:30  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
130126 10:56:30 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections. ////// and after that i'm not able to quit or leave this season

Comment: update: after killing mysqld i was able to change the password and login, but after 3-4 minutes its kicked me off phpmyadmin and the error back again

Comment: Try to use another shell to connect to your mysql on the same host while the mysql is running in your first one. Reset the password and kill  the mysql from the same shell. 

After that: restart the mysql with normal /etc/init.d/mysql start

Comment: sorry but i'm newbie to linux how i make that?

Comment: No Problem. I updated the original answer. Try to repeat the steps :)

Comment: i get this error now > mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password'); 
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement
mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Comment: thanks @noqqe for the help, i ended up removing/reinstall mysql-server seems fixed the problem for now going to start fresh everything again sorry for the trouble